# JOOQ timestamp field default value different from the db default value

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a postgreSQL database with the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_acc
(
  name          TEXT                  NOT NULL,
  updated       TIMESTAMP             DEFAULT now()
);
```

And, in using JOOQ, data is inserted as follows (*Kotlin language*)

```
val record = create.newRecord(USER_ACC)
record.name = "username"
record.store()
```

And the record is inserted properly in the db, with default timestamp value from now().

```
------------------------------------------
| user      | updated                    |
------------------------------------------
|username   |2018-11-29 14:14:52.635838  |
------------------------------------------
```

**The thing is, The process which exceutes the above JOOQ statement is in a different server from where the database is present. And both are in different timezones.**

**So, if I insert a record directly by connecting to the database, the default timestamp (from now()) is hours apart from what is inserted by JOOQ.**

I believe this is because, in the autogenerated classes for JOOQ, the *updated* field is generated as

```
 /**
 * The column <code>user_acc.updated</code>.
 */
 public final TableField<UserAccRecord, LocalDateTime> UPDATED = createField("updated", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME.defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("now()", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME)), this, "");
```

Does this generate current timestamp (for now()) on the service side, instead of the database generating the default timestamp? If so, how can i make JOOQ skip this, and go with the database's now() value?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a jOOQ question - if you're inserting your record the way you've described, then jOOQ doesn't do anything with that timestamp. It is generated by the database, and then possibly fetched back to the client. But beware, it is of the `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` data type, whose value is `2018-11-29 14:14:52.635838` in whatever time zone you're reading this value. So, a different epoch value depending on the client. This isn't necessarily useful - the best way to prevent this is to use the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type instead, which in PostgreSQL is just a simple UTC timestamp.

Comment: I have another question for generated timestamp column.

Table user_profile, with 3 fields:
* id: UUID, primary key, not null, auto generated
* created: TIMESTAMP, not null, auto generated
* name: VARCHAR

---
dsl.newRecord(Tables.USER_PROFILE).apply {
  name = "My Name";
  insert();
}.into(UserProfile::class.java)
---

UserProfile is a pojo class generated by jooq.
"id" field is updated to the pojo, while "created" field is null.
What is the best way to include the returning value for "created" field?

Comment: @Xuan: Please, can you ask a new question here on Stack Overflow. The comment section is ill suited for new questions.

Comment: @ Lukas sorry. Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75328549/jooq-doesnt-return-auto-generated-value-for-normal-column