# JOOQ doesn't return auto generated value for normal column

Tags: sql, kotlin, jooq

I have table user_profile, with 3 fields:

- id: UUID, primary key, not null, auto generated
- created: TIMESTAMP, not null, auto generated
- name: VARCHAR

Below is my code to insert a new row to the table.

```kotlin
// dsl is DslContext, which is a bean, injected by Spring Boot
dsl.newRecord(Tables.USER_PROFILE).apply {
    name = "My Name"
    insert()
// UserProfile is an immutable pojo class, generated by jooq.
}.into(UserProfile::class.java)
```

In the code above, "id" field (primary key) is updated to the pojo,
while "created" field (normal field) is "null".

What is the "best way" to include the returning value for "created" field?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 flags governing this behaviour:

- [`Settings.returnIdentityOnUpdatableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#returnIdentityOnUpdatableRecord), default `true`
- [`Settings.returnAllOnUpdatableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#returnAllOnUpdatableRecord), default `false`

You want to set the second flag to true as well.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
I can confirm returnAllOnUpdatableRecord works.
But is this possible to make it returns only fields with auto-generated value?
In the example, I would not want to return the "name" field, especially when I have another field with large data.

Comment: @Xuan: Yeah, that might make sense: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14573. In the meantime, you can either use explicit `INSERT .. RETURNING` statements, or implement a `RecordListener` that calls `refresh()` on all the desired columns, right after the `insert()` call, or just call `refresh()` manually.